# Laravel Upload PDF to S3 and set Metadata

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I hope y'all doing fine.
I just spend like 4 hours just trying to figure out how to upload a pdf file to the AWS s3 bucket and set it Metadata Content-Disposition to attachment so when the user clicks the presigned URL it automatically downloads the file
My code look like this:

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->getDriver()->put(
            // FILENAME
            '/lender-statement/' . $lender->user->getName() . '.pdf',
            // FILE
            $pdf->output(),
            // MetaData
            [
                    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="mypdf.pdf"',
                    'Metadata' => [
                            'Content-Type'=> 'application/pdf',
                            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment'
                    ]
            ]
    );
```

But when I check the metadata on teh AWS it's on 'x-amx-metacontent' instead of 'Content-Disposition'

Comment: Did you find out how to set the header?

Comment: @reans you can see it in my answer below. I was having the same issue and finally found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `Content-Disposition` key, use `ContentDisposition` and it will work.

Also, you don't need to use `getDriver()`

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($file_path, $pdf->output(), [
     'ContentDisposition' => 'attachment'
]);
```

Note that this logic of removing `-` from the name is also true for other metadata keys.